# Для чего в методе onCreate() находится параметр Bundle savedInstanceState

Tags: java, android

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score -1):

Так вы сохраняете состяние activity при изменение экрана(поворот,  переход  в  двухэкранный  режим и прочее).

Comment: Тоесть, правильно я понял, что перед изменением экрана я смогу положить в этот Bundle все необходимые мне данные, передав в качестве аргумента?